# Number of combinations in Matlab is missing

Tags: matlab, combinations

I am creating a list of combinations of 3 coefficients. The sum is 1 and the increment for each coefficient is 0.05:

```
s=0;
for x1 = 0 : 0.05 : 1
    for x2 = 0 : 0.05 : (1-x1)
        x3 = 1-x1-x2;
        s=s+1;
        fprintf('%0.2f %0.2f %0.2f \n',x1,x2,x3)
    end
end
```

The number expected is 231 but I got 229.
Checking the result:

```
...
0.85 0.00 0.15 
0.85 0.05 0.10 
0.85 0.10 0.05 
0.90 0.00 0.10 
0.90 0.05 0.05 
0.90 0.10 -0.00 
0.95 0.00 0.05 
1.00 0.00 0.00
```

I found '0.85 0.15 0.00' and '0.95 0.05 0.00' were missing but I can't explain why. Could anyone  give me some hint about this. Much appreciate for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re asking for hints, so I’ll give you some.

Read this Q&A: [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/7328782). Now think about what the upper limit for `x2` (`1-x1`) exactly is and how you get there by incrementing 0 in steps of 0.05.

Comment: Let me know if you need more hints or a more explicit answer. :)

Comment: Many thanks @Cris Luengo, this hint helped me to solve the problem. Best wishes.